# Java Design Implementation-location based

Tags: java, oop

I am bugged by this problem that I would like to see what is the general take on this.

I have a few entities which are departmental stores, convenience stores and food centers etc, which are linked to a database which have a table for which entity to return their relevant information e.g. their name, location etc.

I would like to sort the distance on my application from the user's location to the various landmarks, for example there might be 4 departmental stores, convenience stores and food centers in my db and the output to the user on the application would be

1. Food Center A(100m)
2. Departmental Store A(120m)
3. Food Center B(200m)
4. Convenience Store A(220m) so on and so forth in ascending distance.

It is my understand that if I wanted to sort it in this manner, I would have to look into polymorphism i.e. extend this classes under a common class such as a landmark entity. And create a comparator for the landmark entity.

Just would like to know if there is any other way that I could achieve this sorting based on the distance as what I have in mind is to create an `ArrayList<Landmark>` and add in the various different entities.

Are there any other ways of achieving this?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please be more detailed. what the kind of information (about location) that each entity hold? your code will help here..
By the way, its sounds algorithmic problem more than java problem...

Answer (score 0):

I would use an object, distance intermediate class:

```
@Data
public class ToSort<T> {
    private T entity;
    private double distanceToUser;
}
```

Then implement a comparator for it (based on `distanceToUser`) to sort a list of `ToSort`.

Note: A "multimap" is also possible with distance as key and object as value (like [`TreeMultimap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/TreeMultimap.html), but you need every `T` to be comparable).